# Is there a random sampling function for iphone development that can simulate a coin toss?

Tags: iphone, probability, random

Is there a random sampling function for the iphone?
For example, if you want to flip a coin that returns heads 25% of the times it's flipped, and you want to flip it and see if you get heads this time?  I googled for random sampling probability for iphone and couldn't find anything.

Comment: What's wrong with generating a random number between 0 and 1 and seeing if it's less than 0.25?

Comment: Should have mentioned that as an answer Tal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can use any standard C function in Objective-C, you could use [drand48](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/drand48.html) to obtain a random double in the range [0,1]. Success with probability p is obtained by testing if the value is < p. Ex:

```
if ( drand48() < 0.25 ){
     // This branch will be executed 25% of the time
} else {
     // This branch will be executed 75% of the time
}
```

Comment: I ended up using arc4random() instead, but that's basically what I did.  Thank you for your help.